# Flowout Theorem Part I , John Lee's smooth manifold, page 217.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am having trouble understanding John Lee's proof of Flowout theorem.

> **Theorem 9.20:** Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold $S \subseteq M$ is an embedded $k$-dimensional submanifold and $V \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a smooth vector field that is nowhere tangent to $S$. Let $\theta: \mathfrak{D} \rightarrow M$ be the flow of $V$, let $\mathfrak{O} = (\Bbb R \times S) \cap \mathfrak{D}. $  Let $\Phi = \theta|_{\mathfrak O}$.
>
> 1. $\Phi: \mathfrak{O} \rightarrow M$ is an immersion.
> 2. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t } \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathfrak{O})$ is $\Phi$-related to $V$.

Why is $\mathfrak{O}$  a manifold - **what manifold structure** are we giving it? Why is the map $\Phi$ **smooth** being a restriction?

The latter question requires knowing a coordinate chart on $\mathfrak{O}$...

Comment: I hope i don't get this wrong. The domain flow $D$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}\times M$. So as you say, the intersection $O = (\Bbb{R}\times S) \cap D$ is an open submanifold of $\Bbb{R}\times S$

Comment: I think you are right. Just to check a general statement, if $Q$ is a manifold, $S$ an embedded submanifold of $M$, then is $Q \times S$ an embedded submanifold of $Q \times M$?

Comment: Actually it is still unclear to me now - may you describe the explicit smooth manifold structure on $O$? I don't see why $\Phi$ is smooth. I clarified my question.

Comment: $\Phi = \theta|_O$ is smooth since (1) $\theta : D \to M$ is smooth by fundamental theorem of flow. (2) $O = (R \times S)\cap D$ is an embedded submanifold of $D$, therefore $\Phi = \theta|_O$ is smooth , since it is restriction of smooth map $\theta$ to embedded submanifold $O$.

Comment: I think you are right. If you copy & paste solution, I am happy to give you the upvote. But may you elaborate a little on this part: 
1.  $O$ with manifold structure inherited as open subset of $R \times S$. 
2. $O$ is an embedded submanifold of $D$. 
How is 2. true?

Comment: Ok. I'll try ${}{}$.

Comment: Sorry to bring the unrelevant but still true fact that $O$ is an open submanifold of $R\times S$. Since we are dealing with smooth map whose domain is $D$ it is better to look at $O$ as embedded submanifold of $D$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fundamental Theorem of Flows we know that $\theta : \mathfrak{D} \to M$ is a smooth map, with $\mathfrak{D}$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}\times M$, called the Flow Domain. Now $\mathfrak{D}$ is an open submanifold of $\Bbb{R}\times M$ and so to deal with $\Phi$, we look at $\mathfrak{O} = (\Bbb{R}\times S)\cap \mathfrak{D}$ as an embedded submanifold of $\mathfrak{D}$. We can see this by finding slice charts for $\mathfrak{O} \subseteq \mathfrak{D}$. The passage below is the sketch. Roughly, since $\Bbb{R} \times S$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb{R}\times M$,  its restriction $\mathfrak{O} = (\Bbb{R}\times S)\cap \mathfrak{D}$ to an open submanifold $\mathfrak{D} \subseteq \Bbb{R}\times M$ is also embedded submanifold of $\mathfrak{D}$, by local slice criterion.

> Since $\mathfrak{D} \subseteq \Bbb{R} \times M$ is open, $\mathfrak{D}$ is an open submanifold of $\Bbb{R} \times M$. Now $\mathfrak{O} = (\Bbb{R} \times S) \cap \mathfrak{D}$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathfrak{}$ since it is satisfy local slice condition. Suppose you have a point $(t,p) \in \mathfrak{O} \subseteq \Bbb{R} \times S$. Since $\Bbb{R} \times S$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb{R} \times M$, we have a smooth chart $(U,\varphi)$ in $M$ contain $p$ such that $(\Bbb{R} \times (U\cap S))$ is a single $(k+1)$-slice in $\Bbb{R} \times U$. Now the intersection $(\Bbb{R} \times U)\cap \mathfrak{D}$ is a slice chart for $\mathfrak{O}$ in $\mathfrak{D}$.

The map $\Phi = \theta|_{\mathfrak{O}}$ is smooth, since $(1)$ The flow $\theta : \mathfrak{D} \to M$ is a smooth map by Fundamental Theorem of Flows. $(2)$ $\mathfrak{O}$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathfrak{D}$, and the restriction of any smooth map to an embedded submanifold is also smooth.

Comment: Is it possible to use the fact that open submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}\times M$ are (precisely) embedded submanifolds with co-dimension 0, and their inclusion maps are local diffeomorphsims, hence a smooth submersions.


And the inclusion map of $\iota_{\mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{R}\times M}$ is transverse to the embedded submanifold $\mathbb{R}\times S$? So by Theorem 6.30, their intersection is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}\times M$.

Comment: @Qqqq123123 To be honest. I don't remember my train of thought anymore. You should post as new question. There are excellent and active differential geometer here that I'm sure they're willing to help. Cheers!